# Finding the number of times each word in a hashset occurs in text document

Tags: java, text, classification, bayesian

I'm implementing a Naive Bayes text classification algorithm in Java.

What I have done so far is, declare a hashset called Vocabulary which stores all the unique words from a given text file (test file).

One of the steps in the algorithm is to concatenate all the members of the test files into a single text file. This turns out to be a fairly big file with the words from each file.

Now, I have to count the number of occurrences of each word in the Vocabulary with the concatenated text file. My first guess is to keep a sort of an array structure which contains the frequencies of each word. But then again, I would have way too many entries.

Could anyone please give me better suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary (HashMap) where the words are the keys and the values are the number of occurrences. If the HashSet fits into memory, HashMap should as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Tries and the leaf nodes can store the frequency of the words.